# How to plot the roots of two complex equations?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations, code

I have these two equations as two variables '$a1$' and '$b1$', mentioned below and I want to plot the roots of $a1^{\dagger}*a1$ with respect to P0, which will give me bistable plot with three values. I have tried this given code but not getting three roots of $a1^{\dagger}*a1$, which I want to plot.
If anyone can resolve this, must be appreciated.

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"] 
    A1 = 0;
    B1 = 1;
    del = -1.5;
    g0 = 4.8;
    del0 = 1.5;
    ome = 40;
    k1 = 0.1;
kex = 0.1;
kL = (k1 + kex)/2 - del0*(k1 - kex)/(2*ome);
Gma = 0.5;
sol = Values@
  Flatten@Solve[{I*del*a1 + I*g0*(1 - del/ome)*A1*b1*a1 + 
       I*P0*(1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] + I*P0*g0*B1*b1/(Sqrt[2]*ome) -
        kL/2*a1 - (k1 - kex)*g0/ome*B1*b1*a1 == 
      0, -I*ome*b1 + I*g0*(1 - del0/ome)*A1*Abs[a1]^2/2 + 
       I*P0*g0*B1*a1/(Sqrt[2]*ome) - Gma*b1/2 == 0}, {a1, b1}]
```

{a1→−(3854.71−24.092i)P01.P02−(8331.6−329.861i),b1→−8.17708P021.P02−(8331.6−329.861i)}

```
a1 = sol[[1]] /. P0 -> Subdivide[3, 100];
pts0 = a1 Conjugate[a1] // Chop;
pts = Transpose[{Subdivide[3, 100], pts0}];



 ListLinePlot[pts, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["P0", Bold, 20], Style[" N", Bold, 20]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], PlotLegends -> {"a1"}]
```

I think this code is giving me only the value of '$a1$' but I want to plot the roots of $a1^{\dagger}*a1$ with respect to P0, which will give be a bistable plot. Note that the values of the parameters can be changed to get bistable type behavior.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it is to define a function of P0 and plot that function. After running the code in your first block:

```
a1[P0_] = sol[[1]];
a = a1[#] & /@ Subdivide[3, 100];
ListPlot[a Conjugate[a] // Chop]
```

Comment: May you please elaborate this?

Comment: Sorry it is not giving me bistable plot.

Comment: This plots a1 Conjugate[a1] of the function you wrote above, as you asked.

Comment: @ bill s well, so where should I put this code in the main code as you write above?

Comment: Run/evaluate your first block of code (that defines your function). Then evaluate my code above to plot.

Comment: bill s The output is showing this comment,                                                            
             Set::write: "Tag List in {0. +0.\ I}[P0_] is Protected."                                                        If you are getting the bistable plot then, please post.

Comment: sorry, it's not working.

Comment: If you are getting a Tag List error, then quit the kernel and try again, because the above code plots a graph, though I have no idea what a bistable plot is, I was just plotting the function you defined.

Comment: The data range is `{0, 3}`: `ListPlot[a Conjugate[a] // Chop, DataRange -> {0, 3}]`